# Uncaught TypeError: ele.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have an issue please guide me where is the problem or error in my code. Below is my code of html and JavaScript. when I run this code in visual studio code editor then the code runs perfectly but when I use this code in an online site then it shows error "Uncaught TypeError: ele.addEventListener is not a function".

```
**<input type="text" name="" id="mon" class="key" placeholder="Monday">
<input type="text" name="" id="tues" class="key" placeholder="Tuesday">
<script>
var ele = document.querySelectorAll("#mon, #tues");

ele.addEventListener('keypress', demo);

function demo(){
alert();
}
</script>**
```

Comment: `ele` is a collection of elment**S**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1):

Since `ele` is the NodeList array, You have attached `addEvenListener` to the each Node.

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="mon" class="key" placeholder="Monday">
<input type="text" name="" id="tues" class="key" placeholder="Tuesday">
<script>
var ele = document.querySelectorAll("#mon, #tues");
 for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
     ele[i].addEventListener("click", demo);
 }


function demo(){
alert();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements and not a single element. Therefore, `ele` is an array and it is not possible to add an eventListener to an array directly.

If you wish to add the same `eventListener` for all the elements in `el` array, you will need to iterate its elements and add the listener for each one of them, like this:

```
for(var el of ele){
  el.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    alert();
  });
}
```